# How do I run ls-remote in libgit2sharp without a repository?

Tags: libgit2sharp

I would like to use libgit2sharp to run the equivalent of ls-remote for a remote not currently cloned on my system, the equivalent of:

```
git ls-remote http://www.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
```

In the tests, they all seem to begin with a repository cloning the remote, but I do not want to perform the clone just yet. I just want to make sure that I *can* communicate with the server.

I found this [issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/2923) which talks about the same thing in the underlying library, but since there was no response yet, I wasn't sure if there is a way to do this or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I run ls-remote in libgit2sharp without a repository?

Current version (0.21) doesn't allow it.

Issue **[#985](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/985)** has been created to keep track of this request. Feel free to subscribe to it to be notified of its eventual progress.

Answer (score 0):

It can simply be done using the `ListRemoteReferences` method on `Repository`.

See the example below:

```cs
CredentialsHandler handler = (url, usernameFromUrl, types) =>
{
    return new UsernamePasswordCredentials() 
    { 
        Username = "username", 
        Password = "password"
    };
};

var references = Repository.ListRemoteReferences(myRepoUrl, handler);
```